# How to store ListView to database in C# (installed applications)

Tags: c#, mysql

How to copy the items of ListView to a database? For example: I have a list of installed application from PC in a ListView, how to insert these items into a string column in a database `Programs`?

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     String uninstallKey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";

     RegistryKey r = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(uninstallKey);  

     foreach (String skName in r.GetSubKeyNames())
     {
         RegistryKey rk = r.OpenSubKey(skName); 

         try {
             var displayName = rk.GetValue("DisplayName");
             ListViewItem item;

             if (displayName != null) {
                 item = new ListViewItem(new string [] { displayName.ToString() }); 
                 listView1.Items.Add(item);
             }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)  
         { }
    }
}
```

Help! I need add items to a MySQL database

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you need to do is store **one row per application** that you found. You can do this most efficiently by using a loop, and properly parametrized SQL query to insert the data.

Something like this (I'm not too familiar with MySQL, being a SQL Server guy - maybe my syntax needs a little adjustment to work - but you should get the general idea of how to proceed):

```
// set up connection and define INSERT command
string connectionString = .....(this typically is read from a config file)..... ;

// not sure if you can use @ProgramName as parameter, or ?ProgramName... - seen both
string insertQry = "INSERT INTO Programs(ProgramName) VALUES(@ProgramName);";

// define the connect and command objects
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(insertQry, conn))
{
    // define the parameter(s) *ONCE*, outside of the loop - including their type and max length
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProgramName", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 250);

    // open connection
    conn.Open();

    // now, loop over your applications found in the registry; I'd suggest you put those
    // applications found into a separate List<string> for easier use.....
    foreach(ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
    {
        // set parameter
        cmd.Parameters["@ProgramName"].Value = item.DataItem.ToString();  // would be much simpler with a List<string> ....

        // execute insert query for that parameter value
        int rowsInserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    // close connection
    conn.Close();
}
```

I need to use `item.DataItem` to get at the actual data stored inside the `ListViewItem` object that you've stored your discovered application names in. As I said - if you'd store the application names discovered in the registry into a `List<string> discoveredApplications`, the code would be definitely simpler to write and understand....